# How to get every checkbox status base on same name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
 var vals = [];
 $("body").find('input[name^=tc]:checked').each(function(e){
  console.log(e + $(this).val());
   vals.push($(this).val());
 });
 alert(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1<input type="checkbox" name="tc0" value="Y">
<br />
2<input type="checkbox" name="tc1" value="Y">
<input type="checkbox" name="tc1" value="N">
<br />
3<input type="checkbox" name="tc2" value="Y">
<input type="checkbox" name="tc2" value="N">
<br />

<button id="btn">click</button>
```

If I check Y for tc0, Y for tc1 and Y for tc2, and click the button and I will get Y,Y,Y.

What If I check Y for tc0, nothing for tc1, and N for tc2 and click the button and I will get Y,N.

What I except is to get Y,"",N.

How can I do that?

Comment: Remove `:checked` from selector..As you are not concerned about `checked` state of the element...

Comment: If y and n is checked for tc0

Comment: If remove :checked, I will get all checkbox status. for example, i will get Y,Y,N,Y,N, if I did not check one of them. what I expect os "", "", ""

Comment: What if both ceckbox are checked? How are you expecting output there?

Comment: I will handle that, only one checkbox will be checked for same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all the checkboxes

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var tmp = {};
  var vals = $('input[name^=tc]').map(function(e) {
    var checked = $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]:checked');
    if (!tmp[this.name]) {
      tmp[this.name] = true;
      if (checked.length > 1) {
        return [checked.map(function() {
          return this.value;
        }).get()];
      } else {
        return checked.val() || '';
      }
    };
  }).get();
  snippet.log(JSON.stringify(vals));
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1
<input type="checkbox" name="tc0" value="Y">
<br />2
<input type="checkbox" name="tc1" value="Y">
<input type="checkbox" name="tc1" value="N">
<br />3
<input type="checkbox" name="tc2" value="Y">
<input type="checkbox" name="tc2" value="N">
<br />

<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: can I get array for return ?